# como usar while en java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, while

debo desarrollar el siguiente codigo usando while, pero no se como aplicarlo.

```
package taller;

public class punto4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int m3=0;
        
        for(int i=35;i<=65;i++) {
            
        if (i%3==0) {
            
           m3=m3+i;
            System.out.println("i="+i);
            System.out.println("m3="+m3);
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una respuesta lista para ser usada.
Bastara con eliminar el for-loop y remplazarlo por un while-loop
La variable `i` es el control de paro, puedes incrementar su valor dentro del while-loop o desde los parámetros del mismo while-loop.

```
public class punto4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m3 = 0;
        int i = 35;

        while (++i <= 65) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                m3 = m3 + i;
                System.out.println("i= " + i);
                System.out.println("m3= " + m3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], considera editar y mejorar tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 35;

while (i <= 65)
{
   if(i % 3 == 0)
   {
       //código
   }

   i++;
}
```

Es prácticamente lo mismo solo que esta vez el incremento de la variable es responsabilidad del programador.

Aquí pongo un **ciclo while** con la condición que tú tienes, y después de ejecutar todo el código incremento la **variable i** que nos va a servir de contador y así hasta que se cumple la condición. Una vez que se cumpla la **condición de parada** pues se sale del **ciclo while**.

Importante, aunque es obvio la variable se incrementa dentro del **ciclo while**.